# how to get div element to scroll with page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element that I want to move with the page for when you scroll it, such as in the picture below. but right now it's just sitting in a fixed position. How can I accomplish this?
I know I need to use JS, can someone point me in the right direction ?

[image: scroll]

```
<div id='slider'>


</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for JS you should use position fixed

```
div#slider {    
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use slider instead of div#slider ? (accidentally submitted edit instead of comment)

Comment: in bigger projects it just a good habit to write div#slider, li.list etc. so its more readable nothing more :)

Comment: I disagree, IDs are supposed to be unique elements and the div#slider selector is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use fixed positioning in CSS without JavaScript.

```css
#slider {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#slider {
    position : fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your are looking for [this](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating/jquery.html) kind of functionality. read out full documentation for how to use [here](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating/jquery.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) (  
    {  
        $('#floatdiv').addFloating(  
            {  
                targetRight: 10,  
                targetTop: 10,  
                snap: true  
            });  
    });  
</script>
```